# Rating elements via partial orders

Tags: ordering

I would like to rate a set of $n$ elements, with each element assigned a rating from ${0,\dots, 10}$.

The way in which I want to rate is by repeatedly selecting subsets of $k$ elements and querying a user to rank them relative to each other. I would like a means of minimizing the number of necessary queries to assign ratings (i.e. "how do I pick which elements I should ask about?"), and a way of aggregating my partial orders into the appropriate buckets ("when do I stop, and how do I map the partial order into my range?").

Are there any decent references I should be looking at?

Comment: A ha, thanks for the perspective, that certainly seems like it puts me on the right track (if you care, if you leave that as a response I'll mark it as accepted :), otherwise gonna give this a shot and see if it produces the results I want. Appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're essentially asking is to find a total ordering of a graph of users whose partial orderings are results of querying a user for their relative rank. Your asymptotic complexity of the minimum necessary number of partial orders will relate to the Stirling number of the Second Kind mathworld.wolfram.com/StirlingNumberoftheSecondKind.html. To find this total ordering (re: "how do I map the partial order into my range?") you would topologically sort the graph you're describing. Note that for every vertex, $u\leq_p v\Rightarrow (u,v) \in E$, and the graph would be directed.